# ITK won't autocomplete in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete, vtk, itk

Is there a way to configure autocomplete for ITK libraries in QtCreator? All headers are included, but it still cannot recognize simple -> . Just to mention, I use gcc compiler, not CMake..
I am not dyslexic, but no-autocomplete is pain_in_the_ass...

Appreciate any help,
Nikola

Comment: I can confirm that. Before I thought it was not OK because of the typedef, but it's fixed in new QtCreator version. ITK still not works well.